# "Can't POST w/ nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, postman

I just wanna make an **app.post req.** with postman, but i honestly don't know what's wrong, here's the code:

```
const express = require('express');

const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const app = express();

app.listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

//What im trying to do:

```
**app.post('/test',(req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Hello World')
});**
```

Here's what im doing, step by step:

- npm start (At the terminal, and yes, into the project directory)
     The terminal displays the following:

  ```
         *> node src/index.js
         Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080*
  ```
- Then, with Postman opened, im using the method "post" with the following link:
     **http://0.0.0.0:8080/test**

*The point is, on postman im getting this as response:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /test</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

*Instead of this:*

```
Hello World
```

So...I really don't know what's wrong...

Comment: I tried your code it seems to be working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must note here these two points:

- 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address (also known as localhost).
- 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown, or non-applicable target (a ‘no particular address’ place holder).

Changing HOST to 127.0.0.1 will fix the issue you are facing.

You can read more about the differences between the two [right here](https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/)